# Difference between using IN SELECT and INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, select, inner-join

I want to know if there is performance difference in using

```
SELECT Table1.*
FROM Table1
WHERE Col1 IN (SELECT Col2 FROM Table2)
```

AND

```
SELECT Table1.*
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col2
```

Comment: the latter must be better as the former repeating `(SELECT Col2 FROM Table2)` each Table1 rows

Comment: I would say there isn't any difference since you are only selecting from Table1. But using the second query you can return columns from Table2. Not too sure what it means in terms of index and reads etc

Comment: When in doubt of performance, check the actual queryplan in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: @pfx I dont have permission to Execution plan by our DBA

Comment: @asmgx Sorry to hear, as execution plans are a great tool to see the impact of a query, which helps to write better ones. A better query makes a happier DBA. Should convince him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually joins will work faster than subquery. But sometimes the performance may depend on the data in the tables or other factors.

You can write your SQL by JOIN or SUBQUERY, SQL Server will always transform it on an execution plan.

You can see more: https://www.essentialsql.com/what-is-the-difference-between-a-join-and-subquery/

Answer (score 3):

The two do different things.  The `in` version will not return duplicates.  The `inner join` does return duplicates.

Often, the `inner join` version has better performance, although that depends on the data and the database.

I would generally use `exists`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t2.Col2 = t1.col1);
```

This can directly take advantage of an index on `table2(col2)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Table1.*
FROM Table1
WHERE Col1 IN (SELECT Col2 FROM Table2)
```

In this query, I cannot use any column of table2 in my result set.

If  I need column of both table then I will use INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT Table1.*
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col2
```

In one to one relationship and as per requirement INNER JOIN will perform better.